# Get all Keys from a MultiDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

Im looking for a way to get all FIRST level Keys of a multiDictionary and im totaly unable to get them (its for debugging purpose)

i declared the dictionary like this :

```
        private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Packet>> PacketsStore = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Packet>>();
```

So how can i print out a list of all the base keys?

how could i then print out the second level keys incase i need it too later...

thanks in advance!

Comment: `PacketsStore.Keys`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, Packet>> entry in PacketsStore)
{
    string key = entry.Key; // first level
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Packet> entryInner in entry.Value)
    {
       string keyInner = entryInner.Key // second level
    }
}
```

I have taken keys into variables you can take the same into some collection. Purpose was to get keys :)

Comment: raises an exception : `'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll`... doing a `packetsStore.count()` returns me `0`... so maybe my problem is in the fact the dictionnary is empty! ill check this out and come back!

Comment: @user3916429 after checking that see the updated answer, was silly mistake there

Comment: yes it works perfectly, i was gonna submit the fixed code too ^^ My problem came from the fact my Dictionary was always empty ... Now its working perfectly and yoru code is working :) I will just add a check for empty Dictionary tho for safety. thank you

Comment: @user3916429 Do you really prefer to get subkeys using an explicit double `foreach` instead of `Enumerable.SelectMany`?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Sorry, it was only for Debugging purpose, so i could simply dump all of the Dictionary to the Console. It was easier for that purpose only, but using your `Enumerable.SelectMany` will be way easier to use inside code if someone needs to only get the subkeys without looping though the first key pair yes!

Answer (score 2):

First level, the well-known way:

```
var allKeys = PacketsStore.Keys;
```

Sub-dictionary keys, the LINQ way:

```
var allSubKeys = PacketsStore.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Keys);
```

OP has commented out on other answer that the two nested `foreach` loops were more suitable for debugging purposes, but, after all, if OP wants to output all subkeys to console, it can still be done with a one-liner solution:

```
// One-liner solution!
PacketsStore.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value.Keys).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

For all keys, try:

```
var keys = PacketsStore.Keys.ToArray();
```

and for second level keys:

```
List<string> secondaryKeys;
foreach (var key in keys)
{
     secondaryKeys.AddRange(PacketStore[key].Keys.ToArray());
}
```